# NextJS image The resource [link of image] was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event

Tags: reactjs, typescript, image, next.js

I'm using next/image in NextJS for my blog website, but I noticed the following warning in my console:

```
The resource http://localhost:3000/_next/image... was preloaded using link preload but not used within a few seconds from the window's load event. Please make sure it has an appropriate `as` value and it is preloaded intentionally.
```

The image is above the fold and should not be lazyloaded. That's the reason why I used `priority` on the image. If I remove it, the following warning pops up:

```
react_devtools_backend.js:4026 Image with src "/media/image1.jpg" was detected as the Largest Contentful Paint (LCP). Please add the "priority" property if this image is above the fold.
Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#priority
```

The code:

```
<div className={`image-container article-page__banner"`} >
            <Image
                className="article-page__banner"
                src={metadata.banner}
                alt={"Article banner"}
                width={1000}
                height={500}
                layout="responsive"
                objectFit="cover"
                priority
            />
        </div>
```

I saw that the warning is only happening in Chrome and only when strict mode is true. Is there a specific reason for this warning? I can probably ignore it, but I wanted to know what the reason behind it is.

(Tech stack: NextJS and website is SSG + TypeScript)

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the priority to true,

the default value is false

so try this

```
<div className={`image-container article-page__banner"`} >
        <Image
            className="article-page__banner"
            src={metadata.banner}
            alt={"Article banner"}
            width={1000}
            height={500}
            layout="responsive"
            objectFit="cover"
            priority={true}
        />
    </div>
```

Comment: Already added that, look at the snippet above. I added `priority`, which is the same as priority={true}